# Error : _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Where do I need to fix this? It shows error : **"_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')"**  in readUserRideRequestInformation

```
class PushNotificationSystem
{
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future initializeCloudMessaging(BuildContext context) async
  

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? remoteMessage)
    {
      //display ride request information - user information who request a ride
      readUserRideRequestInformation(remoteMessage!.data["rideRequestId"], context);
    });
  }
```

function

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class UserRideRequestInformation
{
  LatLng? originLatLng;
  LatLng? destinationLatLng;
  String? originAddress;
  String? destinationAddress;
  String? rideRequestId;

  UserRideRequestInformation({
    this.originLatLng,
    this.destinationLatLng,
    this.originAddress,
    this.destinationAddress,
    this.rideRequestId,
  });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjN76.jpg)

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using bang `!`, you can do a null check, or use string format to pass null.

```dart
 final rideRequestId = remoteMessage?.data["rideRequestId"];
 if(rideRequestId != null){
    readUserRideRequestInformation(rideRequestId, context);
  }
```

Comment: Find more about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Still can't fix it like before

Comment: is it cumming from same place ?

Comment: yes cumming from same

Comment: try update snippet, reading map can provide null